# MongoDB Find Next Document or Go To First

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have an Express app with Node / MongoDB / Mongoose ODM. The app displays data about projects stored in the DB, and each project page should have a link to the previous and next project (the link is also stored in the DB). If the app is at the last project in the DB, how can I query the database for the first project, instead of looking for the (non-existent) next one?

```
app.get('/projects/:_id', function(req, res){
var nextProject = Project.find({_id: {$gt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1)
var prevProject = Project.find({_id: {$lt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1)
Project.findById(req.params._id, function(err, foundProject){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error finding project');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
      nextProject.exec(function(err, next){
        if(err){
          console.log('err');
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          prevProject.exec(function(err, prev){
            if(err){
              console.log('err');
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(prev[0].title);
              console.log('==============================================');
              console.log(foundProject);
              console.log('==============================================');
              console.log(next[0].title);
              res.render('project', {project: foundProject, nextProject: next[0], prevProject: prev[0]});
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you!

**EDIT** (New code trying to retrieve first document if 'next' comes back empty...

```
app.get('/projects/:_id', function(req, res){
Project.find({_id: {$gt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1), function(err, next){
  if(err){
    console.log('err getting next project');
    console.log(err);
  } else if(next){
    var nextProject = next
    console.log('this is the next project');
    console.log(nextProject);
  } else {
    var nextProject = Project.find().sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1);
    console.log('this is the first project');
    console.log(nextProject);
  }
}
Project.find({_id: {$lt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1), function(err, prev){
  if(err){
    console.log('error getting previous project');
    console.log(err);
  } else if(prev){
    var prevProject = prev
    console.log('this is the previous project');
    console.log('prevProject');
  } else {
    var prevProject = Project.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1);
    console.log('this is the last project');
    console.log(prevProject);
  }
}
Project.findById(req.params._id, function(err, foundProject){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error finding project');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
      nextProject.exec(function(err, next){
        if(err){
          console.log('err');
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          prevProject.exec(function(err, prev){
            if(err){
              console.log('err');
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(prev[0].title);
              console.log('==============================================');
              console.log(foundProject);
              console.log('==============================================');
              console.log(next[0].title);
              res.render('project', {project: foundProject, nextProject: next[0], prevProject: prev[0]});
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
});
```

**2nd Edit** with more code that isn't working:

```
app.get('/projects/:_id', function(req, res){
  var nextProject = Project.find({_id: {$gt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1)
  var prevProject = Project.find({_id: {$lt: req.params._id}}).sort({_id: -1 }).limit(1)
  // find the project for the clicked link
  Project.findById(req.params._id, function(err, foundProject){
    if(err){ // handle any errors
      console.log('Error finding project');
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      nextProject.exec(function(err, next){ // if no errors, execute the query object for the next project
    if(err){ // handle any errors
      console.log('Error getting next project');
      console.log(err);
    } else if(next){ // if next has a value...
      prevProject.exec(function(err, prev){ // ... execute the query object for the previous project
        if(err){  // handle any errors
          console.log('error getting previous project');
          console.log(err);
        } else if(prev){ // if previous has a value...
          console.log('prev and next have a value');
          console.log('============================foundProject============================');
          console.log(foundProject);
          console.log('============================prevProject============================');
          console.log(prev);
          console.log('============================nextProject============================');
          console.log(next);
          res.render('project', {project: foundProject, nextProject: next[0], prevProject: prev[0]});//... render the project page with current project, next project and previous project
        } else if(prev){ // if previous doesn't have a value...
          var prevProject = Project.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1);//... get a query object for the last document in the database
          prevProject.exec(function(err, prev){ // execute the query object for the last document
            if(err){ // handle any errors
              console.log('error getting last document');
              console.log(err);
            } else { // with no errors...
              console.log('next has a value, but previous does not. Gone to last project');
              res.render('project', {project: foundProject, nextProject: next[0], prevProject: prev[0]}); // ... render the page
            }
          })
        }
      })
    } else if(next){ //if next doesn't have a value...
      var nextProject = Project.find().sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1);//get a query object for the first document
      nextProject.exec(function(err, next){ // execute the query object
        if(err){
          console.log('error getting first project');
          console.log(err);
        } else { // with no errors...
          console.log('previous has a value, but next does not. Gone to first project');
          res.render('project', {project: foundProject, nextProject: next[0], prevProject: prev[0]});//render the page
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say :

> the link is also stored in the DB

**(1) Store links with each project**

The `next` and `previous` links could be stored within `project`, then you wouldn't need to fetch anything in the database to display them.

It does require that you update a project's links when a linked project is deleted. But that may not happen too often ?

---

**(2) Find first document when next fails**

Otherwise, with your current code, if `nextProject` returns nothing, you could do:

```
nextProject = Project.find().sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1).
```

---

**(3) Use Aggregate**

If you know your first document's _id, you could use aggregate:

```
$ Project.aggregate([{
             $match: {
               $or: [{_id: {$gt: req.params._id}}, 
                     {_id: lowerId} ] }}, 
             {$sort: {_id: -1}}, 
             {$limit: 1}
         ])
```

But if you know the first document, I would instead :

- keep the first document in memory;
- try to load the next one;
- if it fails, take the first document.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Alex! Your snippet works to get the first entry, but I can't figure out how to get the next entry if there is one, and if not, then get the first entry... I'm pretty new to MongoDB, and I'm not sure of the syntax. I've been trying things like: 

`var nextProject = Project.find({ $or: [ {<expression 1>}, { <expression 2> } ] } )`

But maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree...?

Comment: I would just execute the first query, and if the result is empty, do the second one.

Comment: updated with an aggregate example. However, I'm only able to make it work if you already know the first document's id. And if that is the case, you could just as easily keep the first document in memory.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this Alex! I think option 2 suits my situation best. I tried to implement it, but nextProject comes back as undefined. I'll update my original question with the new code...

Comment: Which line exactly is returning undefined ?   "var nextProject = Project.find().sort({_id: 1 }).limit(1);"    this ?

Comment: It's the line `nextProject.exec(function(err, next){` which is returning undefined

Comment: Ah yes, I took `var nextProject =` away because when I added the callback function in the latest code, I was getting an error saying that .sort is not a function. So I was trying to declare nextProject later on, and assign it the returned value `next`.

Comment: I've made another edit with my latest incarnation of code. The code runs, but it still passes through an empty 'next' array when looking for the next project from the last project (or the previous project from the first one).

Comment: shouldn't "else if(next){ //if next doesn't have a value..." be changed for just en "else" ?   I think the previous should look like "if(err), else-if(prev), else"

Comment: Yep well spotted, that'll teach me to code way past my bed time. After sorting those if/else statements out, I also added `else if ( next.length > 0 ) {` // then it has a value and the code should execute. I guess it wasn't working before because even if next is an empty array, it still exists, so `if (next)` will always be true. Thanks again Alex, I owe you a beer.

Comment: Mongoose has .limit and .skip specifically for this.  They are built in.